# plot multiple curves on same plot inside function

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

I have a following function with takes 2 arguments `psi,lam` and returns 1 array `y`.

```
lam=np.arange(0,1,0.1)
psi=np.deg2rad(np.arange(0,361,1))

def test(psi,lam):

    y=[]
    
    for i in range(len(lam)):
        sin_psi  = np.sin(psi)
        cos_psi  = np.cos(psi)
        sin_beta = lam*sin_psi
        cos_beta = np.sqrt(1.0 - sin_beta**2)
        ssin_pb  = sin_psi*sin_beta
        y.append((lam*(cos_psi/cos_beta)**2 - ssin_pb)/cos_beta + cos_psi)
        plt.plot(psi,y[i])
    
return y
```

I would like the function to return `range(len(lam))=10` plots of `y` on the vertical axis  against `psi` on x axis.

However, it seems to be only plotting the same curve multiple times. Not sure what I am missing?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `sin_beta = lam[i]*sin_psi`?  And also `y.append((lam[i[*(cos_psi/cos_beta)**2 ...))`? A more "pythonic" approach would use `for lam_i in lam:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

lam=np.arange(0,1,0.1)
psi=np.deg2rad(np.arange(0,361,1))

def test(angle,var):
    sin_psi  = np.sin(psi)
    cos_psi  = np.cos(psi)
    sin_beta = var*sin_psi
    cos_beta = np.sqrt(1.0 - sin_beta**2)
    ssin_pb  = sin_psi*sin_beta
    return ((var*(cos_psi/cos_beta)**2 - ssin_pb)/cos_beta + cos_psi)

for i in lam:
    plt.plot(psi,test(psi,i))
plt.show()
```

I moved the variable outside of the function, this way you may also use it for other cases. The only other thing is that you should call `plt.show()` after you're done drawing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several problems the main being that the return function was inside the loop interrupting it after the first iteration. Imitating your code structure as closely as possible, we can rewrite the code as:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def test(psi,lam):
    y=[]
    
    for curr_lam in lam:
        sin_psi  = np.sin(psi)
        cos_psi  = np.cos(psi)
        sin_beta = curr_lam*sin_psi
        cos_beta = np.sqrt(1.0 - sin_beta**2)
        ssin_pb  = sin_psi*sin_beta
        val = (curr_lam * (cos_psi/cos_beta)**2 - ssin_pb)/cos_beta + cos_psi
        y.append(val)
        plt.plot(psi, val)   
        
    plt.show()
    return y


lam=np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
psi=np.deg2rad(np.arange(0,361,1))

y = test(psi, lam)
print(y)
```

Sample output:
[image]

As Johan mentioned in the comments, you should also directly iterate over list/arrays. If you need to combine arrays, use

```
for x1, x2 in zip(arr1, arr2):
```

If you absolutely need the index value, use

```
for i, x in enumerate(arr):
```

Comment: Although this is closer to the example from the question, wouldn't it still be a better option to extract the lam iteration and get rid of the extra list? I just rewrote the program to something that I would consider more "useful", but if the desired result was both the plot and the list, your answer would be more correct.

Comment: @Tempman383838 Well, we don't know. The OP hasn't specified what the expected outcome is. We both had a guess what they intended to achieve.